# Is there a system variable that stores the location of a user's Dropbox?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, dropbox

At least in the linux version of [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com), the user can choose which folder becomes their Dropbox. Is there a simple way to get this programmatically?

Comment: i am just guessing here, but have you tried changing the directory then checking in the config files if dropbox saved the directory in an easy to change manor ? Most linux software use text files for configs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will give you a clue. http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/TextBasedLinuxInstall

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox configuration is stored in a sqlite database in your ~/.dropbox folder.

I found a small script which edits the Dropbox folder location:
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/119154/permalink/dropboxdir.py
http://cmdlinetips.com/2012/05/how-to-change-dropboxs-default-directory-location/

The most forward way to force Dropbox to use another folder location is a symbolic link.
Stop the dropbox daemon and simply replace the default folder with a symlink:

```
> mv ~/Dropbox /other/dropbox/folder
> ln -s /other/dropbox/folder ~/Dropbox
```